# CSV Import into SQL Server table(s)

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a spreadsheet which is laid out

```
ITEM NAME    TAG1    TAG2     TAG3
Hats           X       X
Socks          X                X
Pants                  X        X
```

and I have 3 DB tables

- Items - PK_ItemId
- Tags - PK_TagId
- ItemTags - PK_ItemId_TagId

How can I import the data from the spreadsheet into the correct mapping in `ItemTags` where the column has an X?

Comment: How many possible TAG columns are there? Where does the data come from - is it manually entered into the spreadsheet? What have you tried so far? What platform are you comfortable developing in?

Comment: All the data is manually entered into the spreadsheet (as in the X in the appropriate column)... The columns, they come from the DB and are a fixed number of columns/tag (12).  Likewise the item names are from the db also.  I tried importing the csv into a temp table including the first row as headers, which worked fine, but the only way I can see to get the data into the relevant tables, is with a really long ugly query with a bunch of case statements for each column, but would like something I can re-use later preferably, so need to be able to do it on the fly, looking up the ID's as we go

Comment: I could do this easily in C#, but was hoping to do it all SqlServer side

Comment: That is exactly what I would recommend - import into a staging table then update from that. In coding terms it's no uglier than the C# code that you would need to do it. The main risk is when a new tag appears.In this case C# probably has a bit of an edge.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid I was just hoping there was a nicer way to do it

Comment: Maybe your SQL code could be made nicer but you'd have to post it. But regardless when interfacing with a relational database you need to be explicit about columns and metadata